# Fix table with incorrect records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users with state and country field. I have state and country tables with fields code and name. Some of the user records are polluted with name values, and I need to fix the users table to change all the values for state and country to the corresponding code, if it is not already a code. I could manually execute a query to set each name to the code, but I feel like since I already have this data in a table there must be a way to kill all the birds with a stone or two. Thanks.

Edit: I have other problems also, but here I am just looking to correct all state values that are the name, 'California' to 'CA'.

Answer (score 2):

You should determine what types of scenarios you have.  For example California could be CA, California or perhaps someone misspelled it

Run something like the following and begin updating the problem rows.

```
Select Distinct State
FROM UserTable
Where Not in ('CA', 'OH', ....);
```

This will help you determine the discrepancies. Do the same for countries.